# Program does not end when plotting in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm actually plotting a stacked bar and line chart together but to simplify the code I'm showing a simple bar chart only.

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

window = Tk()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
name = ['a', 'b', 'c']
score = [1, 2, 3]
ax.bar(name, score)
plt.savefig('Figure1.png')

window.mainloop()
```

The code itself is doing fine, the issue is when I exit tkinter GUI, the program does not close completely, as seen in powershell

```
PS C:\Users\Desktop> python temp.py
|
```

Without the plotting it will look like this after exiting tkinter GUI

```
PS C:\Users\Desktop> python temp.py
PS C:\Users\Desktop> |
```

I believe there is some extra closing code I need after plotting the figure in tkinter?

Comment: The correct way is to use `Figure` instead of `pyplot` when you combine `tkinter` with `matplotlib`. See the official [sample](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html). Then your GUI will properly exit without the need for extra protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the figure as well.  Bind a function to `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` protocol and close the figure inside the function:

```
...

def on_quit():
    plt.close('all')
    window.destroy()

window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_quit)
window.mainloop()
```